# WCF methods sharing a dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, thread-safety

I'm creating a WCF Service Library and I have a question regarding thread-safety consuming a method inside this library, here is the full implementation that I have until now.

```
namespace WCFConfiguration
{
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
    public class ConfigurationService : IConfigurationService
    {
        ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<string,string>, string> configurationDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<string,string>, string>();

        public void Configuration(IEnumerable<Configuration> configurationSet)
        {
            Tuple<string, string> lookupStrings;
            foreach (var config in configurationSet)
            {
                lookupStrings = new Tuple<string, string>(config.BoxType, config.Size);
                configurationDictionary.TryAdd(lookupStrings, config.RowNumber);
            }
        }

        public void ScanReceived(string boxType, string size, string packerId = null)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Imagine that I have a 10 values in my configurationDictionary and many people want to query this dictionary consuming ScanReceived method, are those 10 values be shared for each of the clients that request ScanReceived? Do I need to change my ServiceBehavior?

The Configuration method is only consumed by one person by the way.

Comment: Your service has ConcurrencyMode.Single so you won't get concurrency issues.  Furthermore, ScanReceived has no code so I'm pretty sure you'll be safe calling a no-op method returning void.

Comment: I'm still working on the code of ScanReceived but it will change to an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an `InstanceContextMode` of `PerCall` you should get a new instance of your service and your dictionary every time a remote call comes in (which I'm assuming will be either `Configuration()` or `ScanReceived()`). This won't share `configurationDictionary` between multiple clients.

With a `ConcurrencyMode` of `Single` you'll only ever have a single thread running your code at any one time. So any issues of concurrency are moot.

Two ways to share `configurationDictionary`:

1. Make it static: `private readonly static ConcurrentDictionary<...> ...`
2. Change your `InstanceContextMode`, and possibly your `ConcurrencyMode`.

I'd recommend the first option if you're not expecting thousands of calls to your service per second.

MSDN has some information about [InstanceContextMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.instancecontextmode.aspx) and [instancing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752230.aspx) of service classes.

---

If you change to `InstanceContextMode.Single` and `ConcurrencyMode.Multiple` you can get many threads executing at once and you will need to worry about synchronised access.

The main thing to watch out for is that when you're querying / iterating over your dictionary, someone else might modify it. Grabbing a snapshot of the dictionary and then querying the snapshot should get around that problem:

```
foreach (var x in configurationDictionary.ToArray())
{
     ....
}
```

Or, if you're using LINQ:

```
var someResult = configurationDictionary.ToArray().Where(...).Select(...)
```

Comment: I don't know how many calls I'm going to get, but I'm pretty sure this will come in an order, I was recommended to make a singleton on this but I don't know if this is a good approach.

Comment: what if I set the property like this:

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]

??

Comment: Both single means one instance of your service class and only ever one thread. The implication is you can only ever service one request at a time. Which means no concurrency issues, but your service can't support lots of clients (I think requests are queued if one is already in progress).

Comment: So, long story short, both single will be OK for your purposes if you only have a few clients.

Comment: I don't know if worth mention it, but the ScanRecieved method will be sending a string over TCP connection to a handled device printer, that is why I needed to be in sequence.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of your context, but setting both options to `Single` should keep things in sequence. Try it with a few clients and see what happens!