# can you expose the progress of a web service to a client - WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, service

I have a service that does image processing. The time that it takes for the process to complete is something like 2-3 minutes.
Can I update the client with the progress of the service? can I somehow tell the client that process reached step3 or something like that?

I am using WCF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can. Use some asynchronous method of WCF to get image processing % value. I mean you have to create this method. And on the client side you have to call this method periodically.

Comment: So you suggest updating the progress in a database

Comment: You have to find a way to share % value between the method which does image processing and async. methods is going to provide to the client this value. Probably it could be a database... Also you can have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815087/wcf-methods-sharing-a-dictionary. If you will use a database approach make sure that this value belongs to certain user session as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the duplex bindings, which supports two way communication:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx

It works using a callback mechanism.

Comment: Is it just Microsoft specific? Cn I have a Java client?

Comment: This is Microsoft specific as far as I know.

Answer (score -1):

This is baked into a couple of the .NET assemblies.  Have you looked at the WebClient class for example?  There are *ProcessChanged event handlers, like DownloadProgressChanged.

Just add these in and wrap them around your methods that take time, e.g. ProcessImage().

Comment: What do you mean this doesn't apply to WCF?  My answer or Ryan's question?  If you are talking about my answer, since when is WebClient not part of WCF?

Comment: WebClient is part of .NET since version 1.0. WCF came with version 3.0.